# How to get count of result from below query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query which is currently returning two results

```
SELECT h1.*
FROM profile AS h1
  INNER JOIN profile h2
    ON (h1.memid = h2.ph_memid
        AND h1.ph_memid = h2.memid)
WHERE h1.event_id = '5496'
```

But I am trying to get only no of result like 1 or 2.... Condition is that 329 and 399 must me in both the columns having same event id
mean

```
memid ph_memid 
 329      399
399       329
```

where event id for this both the result must be same.Here it is 1.
table schema is at
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d4f1/1
Please help.

Comment: you want in php or mysql ?

Comment: i want it in mysql query yes

Comment: this is not about duplicate its about like if some likes u then he also likes then there will be 2 entries but i want 2 as 1

Comment: can you post the expected output?

Comment: yes its like 
COUNT(*) 1

Comment: what about `SELECT count(*)
FROM profile AS h1
  INNER JOIN profile h2
    ON (h1.memid = h2.ph_memid
        AND h1.ph_memid = h2.memid)
WHERE h1.event_id = '5496'`

Comment: its giving 2 as result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tuples (329,399) and (399,329) are equal regarding that they have the same values, i.e. their lower value (329) is equal and their higher value (399) is equal. So use a distinct select on lower and higher value to get one record instead of two:

```
SELECT DISTINCT least(h1.memid, h1.ph_memid), greatest(h1.memid, h1.ph_memid)
FROM profile h1
INNER JOIN profile h2 ON h1.memid = h2.ph_memid AND h1.ph_memid = h2.memid
WHERE h1.event_id = '5496';
```

By the way, you don't restrict h2 to event_id = '5496'. Is this on purpose?

Here is the SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d4f1/25

EDIT: If it is just the count, you are interested in, use COUNT(DISTINCT ...):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT least(h1.memid, h1.ph_memid), greatest(h1.memid, h1.ph_memid))
FROM profile h1
INNER JOIN profile h2 ON h1.memid = h2.ph_memid AND h1.ph_memid = h2.memid
WHERE h1.event_id = '5496';
```

Comment: can you suggest reference to improve query .. I mean some books or reference URl for study of sql

Comment: Sorry I can't. There are certainly good books on this topic (some general ones, some for particular dbms), but I don't know any. I have been using SQL for some twenty years now, so I just have much experience - and thus know what I have to google for :-)

Answer (score 1):

This perhaps you need i.e. group by and count()

```
SELECT h1.*,count(*) as `tot`
FROM profile AS h1
  INNER JOIN profile h2
    ON (h1.memid = h2.ph_memid
        AND h1.ph_memid = h2.memid)
WHERE h1.event_id = '5496'
group by `h1`.`event_id`
```

If you want to shrink down more i.e. count with respect to dt (date) you will need to add the 2nd group by clause as

```
SELECT h1.*,count(*) as `tot`
FROM profile AS h1
  INNER JOIN profile h2
    ON (h1.memid = h2.ph_memid
        AND h1.ph_memid = h2.memid)
WHERE h1.event_id = '5496'
group by `h1`.`event_id` , `h1`.`dt`
```

Comment: No this is giving tot as 2 but actually its 1

Comment: From you sqlfiddle you have (1, 329, 399, 5496, '2014-02-11 04:01:06'),
(2, 399, 329, 5496, '2014-02-11 04:01:14') if you do current way it will return 2 but if you add another group by dt then for each date time you will get 1 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d4f1/26

Comment: but that will individual tot as 1 but requirement is both rows must be counted as 1

Comment: Think you need to group by h1.memid and h1.ph_memid. Otherwise if there were multiple duplicate pairs for an event only one of those pairs would be returned.